# Shift dimensions of a vec3

Tags: c++, performance, glm-math, simplify

### Question

I want to shift the dimensions x, y and z of a three dimensional vector `vec3` by a number n.

```
vec3 shift(int n, vec3 vector);
```

How can I improve my algorithm to get the best performance and simplify the logic? I guess there is a common approach for this task, is it?

### Algorithm

```
vec3 shift(int Dimension, vec3 Vector)
{
    float in[3] = { Vector.x, Vector.y, Vector.z };
    float out[3];
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int n = i + Dimension;
        while(n > Dimension - 1) n -= Dimension;
        out[i] = in[n];
    }
    return vec3(out[0], out[1], out[2]);
}
```

### Example

For example `shift(2, vec3(12, 42, 30))` should give me `vec3(42, 30, 12)`.

- Dimension 0 is x and holds the value 12. It is shifted by 2 to dimension 2 which is z. So z holds 12.
- Dimension 1 is y and holds 42. Shifted by 2 results in dimension 4 which does not exist so we wrap it around and its value becomes the value for dimension 0 which is x.
- Dimension 2 is z and also wraps around the edge and its value lands in y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you can shift 2 times, the third time would be the original again. So instead of making a generic function for 2 different shifts I would recommend to make two simpler functions out of this.

```
vec3 shiftOnce(vec3 Vector)
{
    return vec3(Vector.z, Vector.x, Vector.y);
}

vec3 shiftTwice(vec3 Vector)
{
    return vec3(Vector.y, Vector.z, Vector.x);
}
```

this will be faster and easier to read. I'm not a friend of code duplication, but in small cases like this it's simply the preferred solution.

If you need the dimension parameter:

```
vec3 shift(int dimension, vec3 v)
{
    if(dimension % 3 == 1)      return vec3(v.z, v.x, v.y); // shift once 
    else if(dimension % 3 == 2) return vec3(v.y, v.z, v.x); // shift twice
    else                        return v;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize the algorithm a bit more:

```
// copy a reference of your vector, is better than copy all it´s components.
   vec3 shift (int dimension, const vec3& Vector)
   {
       float in [3] = { Vector.x , Vector.y , Vector.z };
       float out [3];

       for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
              out [ (i + dimension) % 3 ] = in [i];
       return vec3 (out [0], out [1], out [2])
   }
```

in order to shift a vector component, one way, is to get the module of the division
between the sum of the index plus the dimension value, and the dimension of the
vector, wich is three.

for example.
in your case.
input vector (in): 12, 42, 30

dimension : 2

output vector (out)

```
         out [(0 + 2) % 3] = in [0] => out [2%3] = in [0] => out [2] = in [0]
         z holds the value of the x component.

         out [(1 + 2) % 3] = in [1] => out [3%3] = in [1] => out [0] = in [1]
         x holds the value of the y component

         out [(2 + 2) % 3] = in [2] => out [4%3] = in [2] => out [1] = in [2]
         y holds the value of z component.
```

so, the output vector must be:
  in [1] , in [2] , in [0] =  vec3 (42,30,12)